# Word order involving a subordinate clause

Tags: verb

Here is the sentence: *Ich hoffe, das Stück hat noch nicht angefangen*

Isnt *hat* supposed to be in the end of the sentence since it is on the subordinate clause?

Like: *Ich hoffe, das Stück noch nicht angefangen hat*?

EDIT: I think I figured it out, Is it because the second part of the sentence is actually a full statement in itself? So the conjugated verb has no obligation to be on the last position?

Comment: Good to know, however I ran across something similar again:

_Und kaum zu Hause angekommen, war der Himmel blau and das Wetter herrlich._

Here the first part is supposed to be subordinate since it does not form a full statement. But why does the main part of the sentence start with the verb _war_?

As far as I know:
When the subordinate clause starts with (or contains?) _und, sondern, aber, denn, oder_, they take up null position so no change of position is required for the verb. But since this is the main part we are talking about. I'm confused...

Comment: Just to clarify in case that the answers to the related questions do not also answer this: Your variant without "dass" and with "hat" at the end is wrong.

Comment: Regarding your other question that you should ask separately: I do not know these rules (just a native speaker, sorry), but the sentence is also complete without "und", so the "und" in a way refers to the whole construction and does not change the word order.

Comment: Thanks, i also felt like I should ask this question alone. I am going to proceed accordingly.

Comment: _Kaum zu Hause angekommen_ is not a subordinate clause; it is a participle construction that is part of the main clause.

Comment: So, just because they are separated by comma does not mean they are meant to be main/subordinate? 
What is the rule of thumb to differentiate this in the future?

Comment: Any _Hauptsatz_ and _Nebensatz_ needs a finite verb.

Comment: I see, but was my reasoning right regarding that _ 
Kaum zu Hause angekommen_ qualifies as an adverb?

That would explain the structure of the sentence, Adverb + Verb + subject + adjective.


I was wondering if I wrote the sentence like: _Der Himmel war blau and das Wetter herrlich kaum zu Hause angekommen_  
Would that be correct?